# How to remove consecutive duplicate atoms in a list

Tags: prolog, declarative

I want to remove consecutive duplicates in a list in prolog. Im new to the language so I am having a hard time understanding how everything works. So far here is what I've come up with:

```
remove_con_dups([X],L) :- L = X.
remove_con_dups([X,Y|_],L) :- X \= Y, L = X.
remove_con_dups([_|T],L) :- remove_dups(T,L).
```

so far if I query remove_con_dups([a,a,a,b,b,a,c],X), it will give me these values

```
X = a,
X = b,
X = a,
X = c.
```

What I want is to have

```
X = [a,b,a,c].
```

I just can't seem to get my head around this. Any help?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
remove_con_dups([X,Y|_], L) :- X \= Y, L = X.
```

fully defines the second argument, `L`, with respect to its connection with the first argument;

```
remove_con_dups( [X,Y|_], LL) :- X \= Y, L = X, LL = [L|T].
```

*partially* defines the second argument, `LL`, as a list with `L` at its *head*.

What remains is to *say something* about its *tail*, `T`:

```
remove_con_dups( [X,Y|R], LL) :- X \= Y, L = X, LL = [L|T],
      remove_con_dups( R, T).
```

The above might not be quite right. Is it `R`? Is it `[Y|R]`? That's for you to define.

Comment: Hi I still cant get it, I rewrote it as remove_con_dups([X,Y|_],LL) :- X \= Y, LL = [X|Y].
remove_con_dups([_|T],L) :- remove_con_dups(T,L). But its still giving me half answers.

Comment: yes, of course, this wasn't meant as a complete solution, just as a hint to get you started. see the other answer for the near complete code.

Answer (score 1):

I think could be simpler, if you handle the positive case only, discarding the first duplicate seen by pattern matching (that is, the head' arguments shape):

```
remove_con_dups([],[]).
remove_con_dups([X,X|T],R) :- remove_con_dups([X|T],R).
remove_con_dups([H|T],[H|R]) :- remove_con_dups(T,R).
```

This fragment needs a cut somewhere, I'll leave as an easy exercise to find the position where to insert it.